# OpenCart 2.3 Проблема с модулем "Купить в один клик с опциями и учетом для opencart 2.3.x"

Tags: opencart

Модуль называется так: Купить в один клик с опциями и учетом для opencart 2.3.x

Проблема такая:
1. Нажимаю купить в 1 клик.
2. Внутри выбираю варианты (размеры товара) и на этом все. Появляется кружок загрузки и не каких больше действий не происходит.
Что может быть?

Comment: Как минимум улетает ajax, кружёк лоадера говорит о том, что отработала функцния beforeSend. В консоли, в девтулзе вашего браузера смотрите ошибки. Если вы используете покупной(или бесплатный) шаблон вместо дефолтного, то скорее всего в нём переписаны классы или переделан DOM так, что функция покупки не цепляется ни за что. Вариантов много, нужен анализ кода.

Comment: Шаблон я использую дефолтный

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий и более подходит формату upwork и т.п.

Comment: Если Вы не разбираетесь с кодом в принципе, то вам нужен фрилансер для решения вашей проблемы. Здесь лишь можете рассчитывать на то, что кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой у этого же модуля.

Comment: Да, я в коде не разбираюсь. Спасибо вам за помощь. Может все-таки. кто-то и сталкивался. Подожду.